# i have made a program in jupyter . it is showing type error missing 1 positional argument 'y'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to pass two arguments as 'x' and 'y' and i have declared both x and y but its showing this error. what i am trying to do is i have a 'csv' file which contains three columns ,i have put two columns in a variable name x using `pandas.read_csv("path of csv file")` and I have put the left column in variable name 'y' .

```
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

I have changed variable name but still same error

```
  import pandas as pd
  pk=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Admin\Music\new.csv")
  pk

 x=pk.drop(columns=['genre'])
 y= pk['genre']

 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
  model=DecisionTreeClassifier
  model.fit(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
pk=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Admin\Music\new.csv")

x = pk.drop(columns=['genre'])
y = pk['genre']


model=DecisionTreeClassifier()
fitted_model = model.fit(x,y)
```

Comment: i forgot that DecisionTreeClassifier is a class of tree. thank you